# Cannot use Publish Layouts because "Title field cannot be hidden"

Tags: mx-title-control

I would like to customize a Publish Layout on a channel that uses MX Title Control but it won't let me save my layout because it errors out with "Title field cannot be hidden"

Any workarounds available?

Thanks!

Comment: It works for moving fields around, but if you try and delete a tab, you get an error without the error message - http://screencast.com/t/c9sgF0qYy3T

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solutions is [MX Title Control 2.8.7](https://github.com/MaxLazar/mx-title-control).
Now Title field will be visible when toolbar is open.

If you will have any errors with this version - send me email.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by using Chrome's Inspector and making the field visible just by adding some CSS to it. This let me save the new layout. Then when the page is reloaded it's hidden again.